# DarkSky Proxy - "Request not sent. ERROR: Longitute or Latitude is missing." - Node JS request URL, not sure why not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, heroku, weather-api

Referencing the Git: https://github.com/devellopah/dark-sky-proxy

I am pretty new to a lot of the concepts shown here, and have gotten pretty close, but can't seem to solve this last step:

DarkSky's api is setup to disallow direct API calls via JQ-> getJson due to their CORS-policy (to protect the API key, makes sense)

As such, I am working through the process of setting up a proxy based on the above git. I have it working at heroku, which is cool, and get the default datetime when I go to my proxy URL, so it appears this is setup properly.

The issue I am having is that there aren't any instructions on the URL to call to make this simple tool work.

See below code which is the whole file I believe is most relevant. The most relevant line starts at the comment:
// DarkSky API

I have tried a whole swath of URLs, but I think the issue is some missing knowledge about Node.js (which I know very little about, sorry if this is a super dumb question)

From the browser I've tried:

- https://MyURL.herokuapp.com/api/v1/json?48.1234,-110.1234
- https://MyURL.herokuapp.com/api/v1/json/48.1234,-110.1234
- https://MyURL.herokuapp.com/api/v1/json&latitude=48.1234&longitude=-110.1234
- https://MyURL.herokuapp.com/api/v1/json/+"48.1234"+","+"-110.1234"
- (etc.)

Also tried from the chrome console:

- jQuery.getJSON('https://MyURL.herokuapp.com/api/v1/json','37.8267','-122.4233')
- jQuery.getJSON('https://MyURL.herokuapp.com/api/v1/json','37.8267,-122.4233')
- jQuery.getJSON('https://MyURL.herokuapp.com/api/v1/json/','37.8267,-122.4233')
- jQuery.getJSON('https://MyURL.herokuapp.com/api/v1/json/','37.8267','-122.4233')

When I go to the root of the url I get the proper:

- Current time is: 4/6/2019, 5:24:31 PM

However, when trying to actually get this to work, all of the above URLS and trials all return the same:

- Request not sent. ERROR: Longitute or Latitude is missing.

Question: Can someone help me understand what it is I am missing here?
I would love a relevant source to read up on whatever knowledge I am missing.

Appreciate your time for reading this far down!

Source code of the relevant file here:

```
// load environment variables from .env file
require('dotenv').config()

const path = require('path')

const express = require('express')
const favicon = require('serve-favicon')
const cors = require('cors')

const DarkSky = require('dark-sky')
const RateLimit = require('express-rate-limit');

const app = express()

app.use(cors())
app.use(favicon(path.join(process.cwd(), 'favicon.ico')))

app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 3000)

app.enable('trust proxy')

const sleep = 600000; // 10 minutes

// the weather doesn't change too often
const limiter = new RateLimit({
  windowMs: sleep,
  max: 10, // limit each IP to 1 requests per windowMs
  delayMs: 0 // disable delaying - full speed until the max limit is reached
})

// Home
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.send(`<div>Current time is: ${ new Date().toLocaleString() }</div>`)
})

// DarkSky API
const forecast = new DarkSky(process.env.API_KEY)

app.get('/api/v1/json', limiter, (req, res) => {
  const { lat, lon, units } = req.query

  forecast
    .latitude(lat)
    .longitude(lon)
    .units(units)
    .language('en')
    .exclude('minutely,hourly,daily,alerts,flags')
    .get()
    .then(weather => res.status(200).json(weather))
    .catch(error => res.send(error))
})

app.listen(
  app.get('port'),
  () => console.log(`Server is listening at port ${app.get('port')}`)
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out!

There was reference to a query string component, which sent me down the learning road.

Here's the format, for anyone in future stumbling across this:

https://MyURL.herokuapp.com/api/v1/json?lat=42.1234&lon=-117.1234&units=[2lettercountrycode]